# Cross-reference in table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm begginer in VBA and looking for a solution to check something in a table. I would like to create a function that tells if cells in a certain column (range) is not empty only then if the cell in the title column (range) equals something. I tried with a combination of isempty and vlookup but it didn't work.
I hope the description is clear, anyway I attached a simplified table with the problem. Thank you in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLZMK.png)

Comment: where is the attachment?

Comment: so you want to check if the range "B1:E2" is empty, and if it is, what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i have understood your problem 100% but lets begin with what i think i understood, and start with the below:

```
Sub isitEmpty()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    If IsEmpty(.Range("B1:E2")).Value Then
        'do something
    Else
        'do something
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

What do you want to do if the cell is/isnot empty?

Answer (score 0):

Below code works with following assumptions:

1. `Project Type` are listed in `Column A` starting from `Cell A4`
2. `A,B,C,D` category could vary but will always have headings in `Row 3`
3. `Project Type` for which you want the participation as `Y`, are listed in a column that appear after the last column with headings `A,B,C,D`. So as per your image its `Column F`

   ```
   Sub Demo()
       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Dim lRProject As Long, lRMatch As Long, lastColumn As Long, i As Long
       Dim rngProject As Range, celPro As Range, rngMatch As Range, celMatch As Range

       Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5") 'change to your sheet
       With ws
           lastColumn = .Cells(3, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'gives last column with A,B,C,D
           lRProject = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row in Column A
           lRMatch = .Cells(.Rows.count, lastColumn + 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in Column F

           Set rngMatch = .Range(.Cells(1, lastColumn + 1), .Cells(lRMatch, lastColumn + 1))
           Set rngProject = .Range("A4:A" & lRProject)

           For Each celMatch In rngMatch
               For Each celPro In rngProject
                   For i = 2 To lastColumn
                       If celPro.Value = celMatch Then
                           If .Cells(celPro.Row, i) = "X" Then
                               .Cells(celMatch.Row, i) = "Y"
                           End If
                       End If
                   Next i
               Next celPro
           Next celMatch
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

See image for reference.

[image]